# Filter by id of a relation

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to filter in prisma for a relation id and get the same entity, not the related one back. Simple example:

```
type User {
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!

  isOwner: [Meta!]! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "User_Meta_Owner")

  id: ID! @id
}

type Meta {
  owner: User! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "User_Meta_Owner")
  area: Area! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "Meta_Area")

  id: ID! @id
}

type Area {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!

  meta: Meta! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "Meta_Area")
}
```

In this case i want all `Meta` entities which have an owner with the id `userID` and an `Area` with the id `areaID`.

What is possible:

```
ctx.db.user({ id: 'userID' }).isOwner()
```

This gets all `Meta` without a filter for the area.

What i want is something like:

```
ctx.db.user({ id: 'userID' }).isOwner({ where: { area: 'areaID' })
ctx.db.metas({ where: [{ owner: 'userID' }, { area: 'areaID' }] })
```

Since the property area is only a relation, prisma doesnt give me the opportunity to filter or even get the ids.

ie:

```
await ctx.db.user({ id: 'userID' }).isOwner()
```

will result in an array of objects like:

```
[{
  id: '...'
}]
```

My question is, is there any way to get my wanted result without deleting the relation and store simple strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from prisma member to get this currently only working with model like this:

```
type Meta {
  owner: User! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "User_Meta_Owner")
  area: Area! @relation(link: INLINE, name: "Meta_Area")
  ownerId: ID! @db(name: "User")
  areaId: ID! @db(name:"Area")
  id: ID! @id
}
```

So the id's needs to be exposed as scalars, so you can filter those.